# how should i set url in html

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

normally when i calling `localhost:8888/classLevel/spring?name=sachin` like this, its working.

if i want to do like this `@RequestMapping("/spring/{countryName}/{name}")` what should i do. what i have to change in html?. how it will work

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/classLevel")
public class Controaller1 
{
  @RequestMapping("/spring/{countryName}/{name}")
  public ModelAndView display(@RequestParam("name") String name,@RequestParam("countryName") String countryName)
  {
     ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("view");
     model.addObject("msg", name);
     return model;
  }     
}
```

**html page**

```
enter code here

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello App Engine</title>
</head>

<body>
<center><h1>Life Cycle Routine Management</h1></center>

<form action="/classLevel\spring" method="get">
name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="clik me"/>

<a href="BirthCertificateApplicationForm">Birth Certificate Application Form</a>
<br>
<a href="AirlineRegistrationForm">Airline Registration Form</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another say input field in your form like:

```
countryName:<input type="text" name="countryName"/><br>
```

You could even say that your input field is of hidden type and not displayed at all to users.

Comment: `localhost:8888/classLevel/spring/India/sachin` if i give url like this. then what will happen?   each and every time `localhost:8888/classLevel/spring/{countryName}/{name}` country name and name will change. so how i have to set `form action`

Comment: In that case use `@PathParam` instead of `@RequestParam`.